# Unmasking list with .filled()

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, masked-array

I have a masked `list` such as:

```
[masked_array(data = [ 0.12963803],
         mask = False,
   fill_value = 1e+20), 
masked_array(data = 0.22379663389345425,
         mask = False,
   fill_value = 1e+20), 
masked_array(data = [ 0.13113253],
         mask = False,
   fill_value = 1e+20), 
masked_array(data = 0.14300584131111602,
         mask = False,
   fill_value = 1e+20)]
```

Which should be an array, but when I `print(type(name_array))` it returns `<class 'list'>`. I want to **unmask** this object, something like would be

```
name_array.filled()
```

But of course I can not do this since:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filled'
```

If I use `np.array(name_arrray)` it returns an `ndarray` which can not be `.filled()`

I think I am missing something fundamental here, any tip?

Comment: The key point is that you have a list of arrays, not an array.  You can apply `filled` to each element of that list, but you can't apply it to the list as a whole.  How did you generate this list?

Comment: @hpaulj, Thanks! I appended masked elements into an empty array. If you make a real answer I can accept it.